# No se ejecutan acciones del Success en $.Ajax luego de la respuesta JSON de PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Les queria consultar lo siguiente ya que estoy teniendo problemas para obtener la respuesta desde el archivo PHP luego que se procesa la información de un formulario enviado con $.Ajax. A continuación les paso el código que he utilizado:

**main.js:**

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

            var url = "assets/php/contact.php";

            e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: url,
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  success:function(data){

                      var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                      var messageText = data.message;

                      var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';


                       if (messageAlert && messageText) {

                           $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);

                           $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                       }

                   }


              });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**contact.php**

```
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);


if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;

} else {
   echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

via consola de Chrome observo esto pero no ejecuta la secuencia de instrucciones luego del success ( el protocolo que usa el servidor es https )

```
{"type":"success","message":"Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!"}
```

Comment: Qué versión de jQuery estás usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la version 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Desde jQuery 3, las opciones/callbacks `success`, `error` y `complete` [fueron eliminadas](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). En su lugar tenés que utilizar los métodos `.done()`, `.fail()` o `.always()`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function (data) {
    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
    var messageText = data.message;
    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obtengo el mismo resultado, desde la consola veo la interacción del servidor y el echo que al finalizar pero es como que ese eco no viaja de vuelta al js.. por lo tanto no borra la información del formulario ni muestra el mensaje

Comment: Hacé un `console.log(data)` dentro de `.done(data)` y fijate que devuelve.

Comment: En network cuando chequeo me aparece impreso esto: 

{"type":"success","message":"Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!"}

Pero en el console solo me imprime esto:

jquery.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "https://..... ( toda la url del archivo php )

Es como que nada estuviese retornando

Comment: Pusiste el `console.log(data)` al principio del `.done()`? Proba agregar después de `.done()` un `.fail(function () { console.log('fail') });`. A ver si eso no imprime algo.

Comment: El fail si se imprimió en el console por lo que el ajax esta recibiendo eso como respuesta y no como un success.. se envia correctamente el correo pero responde mal el php al ajax

Comment: Probá desde PHP el header `header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');`. En la solapa network del navegador, el status de la respuesta es 200?

Comment: Estoy puliendo el origen del error, sume lo que me mencionaste y me arroja esto:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Se soluciono magicamente, volvi a una version anterior.. le reemplace los metodos de respuesta que habiamos visto a un principio y funciono! Muchas Gracias igualemente @azeos

Comment: Probablemente no sea una buena idea volver a una versión anterior de jQuery. Te recomiendo que sigas revisando a ver donde puede estar el problema.